# Data take on with Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, upload, bulk

We are migrating our current intranet to Drupal 6 and there is a lot of data within the current system which can be classified into:

- List data, general lists of fields. Common use is phone list of the employees phone numbers.
- Document repository. Just basically a web version of a file share for documents.

I can easily get the data + meta infomation out, but how do I bulk upload the two types of data into Drupal, as uploading the hundred of thousands of items manually is just not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Node Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) module which lets you bulk create nodes from CSV or Tab separated files. I can't remember as it's quite a long time ago, but I think I used this when I converted a site from Movable Type to Drupal 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: Problem with it is that it does not handle file attachments :(

Comment: wouldn't it handle your general list data pretty well?

Answer (score 0):

I have been toying with the [services](http://drupal.org/project/services) and [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) modules.  You can use them to move content around.  What you actually end up doing is subscribing your new site to your old site and then the content types/taxonomy you select will move.  I have not tested this yet.  This was only discovered through researching a problem similar to this.  I've used feeds before with great success so this should be a cake walk.

Also this post will get the best results on the [drupal.stackexchange.com](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: The issue was that the source wasn't Drupal, it was another platform and we were moving to Drupal. So subscribing to the old site wouldn't be an option. I agree asking on the Drupal site would've been good, but it didn't exist in September 2009 when I asked this.

Comment: Does the previous system allow for rss/feed aggregation?  Because if it does, my solution should still work.

Comment: Very poorly - only last x items (where x is like 20 or something silly), no attachments etc...

Comment: do you have database access on the old system?  Because you can run queries that export data in a fashion similar to the way node import accepts.